# How to detect if input is from argument, file or terminal

Tags: shell, io-redirection

In bash, is there a way to know if a given script has been invoked with:

```
$ myscript.sh myfile
```

or:

```
$ myscript.sh < myfile
```

Inside some scripts I always have accessed the contents of `myfile` with `$1`, but now I'd like to change the behavior as different cases.

EDIT: I also would like a third case when invoked without any redirection:

```
$ myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**: changed `-t` to `-t 0`, which does correctly detect input from terminal or file.

I think the key here is knowing whether your input is coming from a terminal or from a file.  There is a test for this (`man test`, see `-t`).

Assuming you're running a bash script:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    echo "Input from terminal"
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No input files specified on command line.  Error." >&2
    else
        echo "Input file given on command line.  It is $1"
    fi
else
    echo "Input coming from stdin"
fi
```

You can handle the different scenarios by substituting actual code in for the echo statements above.

Update, quickie test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -t 0 ] && echo "t is true" || echo "t is false"
```

Running:

```
$ test.sh testfile
t is true
$ test.sh < testfile
t is false
$
```

Comment: -t always evaluates to true running the script from the command line with `< myfile` :(

Comment: @mschonaker - Using `-t 0` gives the correct results.  Updated answer.

Comment: @MarkMann What does the `0` do? What is the difference? It's not in the documentation.

Comment: @IvanV. - The zero is the file descriptor to test.  Standard input is associated with `0`, standard output with `1` and standard error with `2`.  If I wanted to check if my output was going to a terminal I would use `[ -t 1 ]`

Comment: @MarkMann Thanks, I thought it might be that, or some kind of Boolean check.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the expressions `$1`, `$2`, etc. expand to the 1st, 2nd,
etc. argument given on the script command line.

So, when you invoke a script as:

```
myscript.sh myfile
```

then `$1` within the script expands to `myfile` (and `$2`, `$3`,
etc. all are the empty string).

When you invoke a script as:

```
myscript < myfile
```

the redirection of STDIN from `myfile` is done by the parent shell, so
the script is actually called with *no* arguments and `$1` expands to
the empty string.

Comment: How do I detect if called with no arguments in the command line (the third case)? Sorry if you answered before my edit. Thanks.